# Get date from Unix Timestamp in Metro style App

Tags: date, c++-cli, windows-runtime

Iam reading out a Json file with a date in it.

```
jsonValue->GetObject()->GetNamedObject("board")->GetNamedNumber("date")
```

That date is saved in Unix code format:

```
"date":1347973494
```

But I need to get it in a normal format like "19.09.2012".
I cant find the right function to solve that problem.
I already tried the DateTimeFormatter class but I think that was not the correct way to make this.

So anyone knows how to change the DateTime from Unix timestamp to a normal format like "19.09.2012"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the Calendar class which you can find [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.calendar.aspx)

```
int unixTimestamp = (int)jsonValue->GetObject()->GetNamedNumber("date");

Windows::Globalization::Calendar^ cal = ref new Windows::Globalization::Calendar();
 cal->Year = 1970;
 cal->Month = 1;
 cal->Day = 1;
 cal->Minute = 0;
 cal->Hour = 0;
 cal->Second = 0;
 cal->AddSeconds(unixTimestamp);

 mainDate -> Text = cal->DayAsString() + ". " + cal->MonthAsString() + " " + cal->YearAsString();
```

Answer (score 1):

A Unix timestamp is seconds since 1970, so add the seconds to 1970-01-01.

```
int unixTimestamp = 1347973494;
System::DateTime timestamp = System::DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(unixTimestamp);
```

Then format the DateTime into whatever string format you like, or use it as a DateTime.

```
System::String^ formatted = timestamp.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")
```

Comment: Your answer is not c++ and doesnt work for me.
I solved the problem 5 Minutes ago but thank you for your help

Comment: You tagged the question C++/CLI. This is C++/CLI code. Since DateTime is a struct, it doesn't need the `^` or keyword `gcnew`, so it looks similar to C# code.